# OpenAI API Quickstart tutorial - POST http://localhost:3000/api/generate 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: openai-api

Im new to OpenAI's API and am following the Quickstart tutorial found here:
https://beta.openai.com/docs/quickstart/build-your-application

I just cloned their GitHub repo (`git clone https://github.com/openai/openai-quickstart-node.git`) and when I tried to run it, I got this error.

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/generate 500 (Internal Server Error)`

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

I don't understand what I missed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[source code](https://github.com/openai/openai-quickstart-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encountered the same issue.

I simply just forgot to do the step involving adding the API_KEY to the .env file.

Follow the instructions from the documentation, specifically the title labelled "Add your API key" (https://beta.openai.com/docs/quickstart/add-your-api-key).

I have attached a screenshot of the instructions here. It is quite clear.

[image]

Hopefully this works for you!

Edit:
Also encountered the same problem when doing large requests. If there is a large request to the OpenAI API (i.e returning many tokens), then it will also return this same error.